# Python 3.9+ Bluetooth on Windows 10

Tags: python, sockets, bluetooth

I've found already very similar questions for this problem but I can't figure it out.
I'm trying to connect a TimeBox evo with bluetooth to windows 10 using python with this code:

```py
import socket

serverMACAddress = "11:75:58:ce:c7:52"
port = 4
print("Start")
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
s.connect((serverMACAddress,port))
while 1:
    text = input()
    if text == "quit":
        break
    s.send(bytes(text, 'UTF-8'))
s.close()
```

and I get this error:

`OSError: [WinError 10064]`

Altough getting the error, the device connects to the PC but I can't send and receive data using Python.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it worked with a port value of 1...